# Tab layout using view pager in android

Tags: android

I have two tabs in tab layout, on activity called i need to directly call tab2 and disable tab1 and tab1 fragment should not be called when i call tab2...
How to implement it in android
Thanks in Advance

Comment: please state your question clear...

Comment: did you want to disable the tab1 or what??

Comment: yes i want to disable tab1 and tab1 fragment should not be called

Comment: i used setcurrentitem() for going to tab2 but my issue is tab1 fragment is also getting called with tab2

Comment: try using .setOffscreenPageLimit(0)

Comment: it will be great if you can explain the use case of .setOffscreenPageLimit(0)?

Comment: off screen page limit is used to store the current status of the fragments that are not visible if you set it to 0 none of your sibling fragments in viewpager will be stored

Comment: ok its about storing...what about disabling?

Comment: so you want to disable the selection of tab1 ???

Comment: setOffScreenPageLimit(value) will keep active/retain the pages on either side of current page. Its default set to 1. If you set it to 2, then two pages will be retain on either side of current page.

Comment: yes i need to disable tab1

Comment: i have worked through it and disabling click is possible but your viewpager swipe will also work in that condition

Comment: if its okay with you then i will post my answer

Comment: swipe action  should also be disable in that case

Comment: post the answer.thanks

Answer (score 0):

to disable the click for specific tab you need to do the following code

```
  LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (i == positionYouNeedToDisable) {
            tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and if you want to disable swipe of you viewpager do the following code

```
        final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```